# gWidgets resize/maximize modal window

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk, gwidgets

My script needs to wait for user input before continuing its processing. After using the R gWidgets package to implement a GUI, I found that the gbasicdialog widget works better than gwindow because it is modal.

The gwindow widget has useful minimize and maximize buttons. The gbasicdialog widget does not have these buttons and I often display large gtables in the GUI, which means the user has to repeatedly click-and-drag to expand the window to see enough of the table.

So far, I adjust the size of the gtable widget as follows:

```
library(gWidget)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
library(RGtk2)
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")

mywindow <- gbasicdialog("Display table", do.buttons = FALSE)
# there can be multiple ggroups to one table, which all occupy the gbasicdialog
mygroup <- ggroup(container = mywindow, horizontal = FALSE) 
mytable <- gtable(a_data_frame, container = mygroup, expand = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
size(mytable) <- c(500, 500) # or any other large enough dimension
exitbutton <- gbutton("Done", container = mywindow, 
                      handler = function(h, ...) {
                      #some steps
                      dispose(mywindow)
                      })
visible(mywindow, TRUE)
```

How can I display the maximize/minimize buttons, or display as much of a large widget as possible, for a interactive/modal window?

Comment: Does calling `size(mywindow) <- c(width, height)` before `visible` do what you want?

Comment: It is satisfactory, but table/data_frame size is subject to change, which means I have to call size for every gbasicdialog and it would be cut off again if I added columns or rows. I want the modal window to maximize automatically or give the user that option with one click.

Comment: What toolkit? That is likely doable, but would require something beyond the gWidgets API. (Not really a big deal in msot cases).

Comment: I'm using RGtk2. I have tried to look at the source code for the widgets in question but it's beyond my current abilities.

Comment: You might have luck with either: `library(RGtk2);  getToolkitWidget(mywindow)$setDecorated(TRUE)` or  `getToolkitWidget(mywindow)$maximize()`.

Comment: getToolkitWidget(mywindow)$setDecorated(TRUE) made little difference. I was thinking that this might make the minimize & maximize buttons appear, which is the best solution. getToolkitWidget(mywindow)$maximize() automatically maximized the window, which I wanted, but it is not the most convenient solution.

Comment: The `setDecorated` bit depends on the OS -- some hide the decorations some don't (like X11 + Mac). Not sure I have any more to add to this -- used up all my tricks. Hopefully the other can be useful.

Comment: The latter will be useful, it's better than what I had before. Please answer below with your two suggestions, then I can accept your solution.

Answer (score 2):

After looking into the Gtk toolkit, there are certain methods that pertain to the [GtkWindow](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/RGtk2/html/GtkWindow.html) and [GtkDialog](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/RGtk2/html/GtkDialog.html). The Maximize method (automatically maximizing the widget) applies to both but the SetDecorated method (displaying upper bar containing minimize,maximize,close buttons) only works for the GtkWindow.

We can obtain the resizing buttons using the gwindow widget while adding a repeat loop to pause execution of the remaining script, maintaining modal/interactive behaviour. The step to automatically maximize the widget, found in jverzani's comments, can also be added to this gwindow.

```
currentenv <- environment() # get current environment
mybool <- FALSE # remains FALSE until the gwindow is closed
mywindow <- gwindow("Display table") 

# Implement auto-maximized gwindow if needed
getToolkitWidget(mywindow)$maximize()

# there can be multiple ggroups to one table, which all occupy the gwindow
mygroup <- ggroup(container = mywindow, horizontal = FALSE) 
mytable <- gtable(a_data_frame, container = mygroup, expand = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
# Upon exit, assign TRUE to variable denoting gwindow is closed
exitbutton <- gbutton("Done", container = mygroup, 
                      handler = {
                          # (some steps)
                          # possibly returning svalue(mytable)

                          # remove ggroup to prevent error
                          delete(mywindow, mygroup) 

                          # close window and confirm closure
                          dispose(mywindow) 
                          assign("mybool", TRUE, envir = currentenv) 
                      })

# Executes repeat loop until mywindow is closed
repeat{
    if(mybool){
        break
    }
}
```